# Should investors add token address to their account to receive the ICO rewards?

Tags: blockchain, ether, myetherwallet, cryptography

I just created a token in blockchain and when I test it on Rikenby network but no tokens appear on my wallet until I added the Token address to watch list.

1- Is that normal that investors should add token address to their account to receive the ICO rewards ?

2- When I added the token to an other account I can change the Decimals! is that normal ? or there is a way to lock Decimals from being changed ?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokens reside in the internal balance of the token contract. It is totally normal to have to enter the address to start “watching” them in your wallet as it needs to know where to look for them.

You can change the decimals but that is read -only. You should always use the decimals the token recommends or you won’t know how many of them you actually have.